# How to remove NaNs and squeeze in a DataFrame - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was doing some coding and realized something, I think there is an easier way of doing this.

So I have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 'A', 2, 'A'], 'b': ['A', 3, 'A', 4]})
   a  b
0  1  A
1  A  3
2  2  A
3  A  4
```

And I want to remove all of the `A`s from the data, but I also want to squeeze in the `DataFrame`, what I mean by squeezing in the `DataFrame` is to have a result of this:

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

I have a solution as follows:

```
a = df['a'][df['a'] != 'A']
b = df['b'][df['b'] != 'A']
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': a.tolist(), 'b': b.tolist()})
print(df2)
```

Which works, but I seem to think there is an easier way, I've stopped coding for a while so not so bright anymore...

**Note:**

All columns have the same amount of `A`s, there is no problem there.

Comment: Can you be certain each series has equal number of “A”s? Otherwise you might have mismatched lengths. You can do “df.replace(‘A’, np.Nan,in place=True)’ instead of your two conditions too.

Comment: @BenP Yes you're right I will edit

Comment: @BenP Edited mine

Comment: ``pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy()[df.to_numpy()!="A"].reshape(-1, 2), columns = df.columns)``. Assuming the columns is 2, and 'A' is exactly one above its replacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do:

```
In [1513]: df.replace('A', np.nan).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().to_numpy()))
Out[1513]: 
     a    b
0  1.0  3.0
1  2.0  4.0
```

Comment: Yeah this looks pretty much there for a dataframe. You could do lambda or list comprehension and filters if you had the raw data in lists too.

Comment: How about reconstruction? This is pretty clean: `pd.DataFrame({c: df[c].replace('A', np.nan).dropna().to_numpy() for c in df})`

Answer (score 3):

You can try boolean indexing with `loc` to remove the `A` values:

```
pd.DataFrame({c: df.loc[df[c] != 'A', c].tolist() for c in df})
```

Result:

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Answer (score 2):

We use can [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) then filter out `'A'` values then [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
out = df.melt().query("value!='A'")
out.index = out.groupby('variable')['variable'].cumcount()
out.pivot(columns='variable', values='value').rename_axis(columns=None)

   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

#### Details

```
out = df.melt().query("value!='A'")

 variable value
0        a     1
2        a     2
5        b     3
7        b     4

# We set this as index so it helps in `df.pivot`
out.groupby('variable')['variable'].cumcount()

0    0
2    1
5    0
7    1
dtype: int64

out.pivot(columns='variable', values='value').rename_axis(columns=None)

   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Another alternative

```
df = df.mask(df.eq('A'))
out = df.stack()
pd.DataFrame(out.groupby(level=1).agg(list).to_dict())

   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

#### Details

```
df = df.mask(df.eq('A'))

     a    b
0    1  NaN
1  NaN    3
2    2  NaN
3  NaN    4

out = df.stack()

0  a    1
1  b    3
2  a    2
3  b    4
dtype: object

pd.DataFrame(out.groupby(level=1).agg(list).to_dict())

   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```